# Can ping but can't do ssh

Tags: openssh

I am able to ping my friend but not able to do ssh. Why so? He is using a modem. I thought there might be some firewall enabled. I told him to type

```
#iptables -F
```

He did that, but still I am not able to do ssh on his system. How can I do this?

I get the error: `ssh: connect to host 182.64.31.131 port 22: Connection refused`

RESULT OF ifconfig on his system

```
 inet addr:127.0.0.1  Mask:255.0.0.0
inet addr:192.168.1.2  Bcast:192.168.1.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
```

He told me his dynamic ip by using whatismyip.com

I tried ssh on that ip.

PS: sshd service is running on his system.
I tried nmap and came to know that port 22 is not opened.

Comment: Does he have an SSH daemon (sshd) running? Also, is he behind a router? If he is, you'll need port forwarding enabled on the router.

Comment: Are you sure that `sshd` is running on that machine? It is listening on all interfaces/addresses (`ListenAddress`)? Are there any entries in `/etc/hosts.deny`? There is a local address at the interface, so is port 22 forwarded to that machine?

Comment: We both have different ISP.

Comment: yes sshd is running.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As @sbtkd85 notes, it's almost certainly because port forwarding needs to be set up at his router/access point.

Here's some related/maybe pertinent info:
http://forum.portforward.com/YaBB.cgi?num=1139203841

Cheers,
Robert

Comment: The hint that NAT is happening between his friend and The Internet is this: inet addr:192.168.1.2   The 192.168.x.x address is a "non-routable" IP address reserved for use inside intranets.